# How to get everything between two words

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

This question is about `regex`.

I am currently using Node.js's child process's `execFile`.
It returns a string, and I'm trying to get an array of names from the multi-lined string like below:

```
   name: Mike
   age: 11

   name: Jake
   age: 20

   name: Jack
   age: 10
```

I've tried:

```
const regex_name = /pool: (.*)\b/gm;
let names = string.match(regex_name);
console.log(names); // returns [ 'name: Mike', 'name: Jake', 'name: Jack' ]
```

But what I want is:

```
['Mike', 'Jake', 'Jack']
```

What should I change in my `regex`?

Comment: This is really close to [YAML](https://yaml.org). Why not go all the way?

Comment: I'm sorry @tadman , but I need more description than ^...

Comment: It's a common [data format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) which would make parsing this as easy as `YAML.load(...)` on your data. You'd basically have to tweak it a tiny bit, so if you have control over the input format that would be easy to fix now.

Comment: @Andy what tadman means is if you're file is standard YAML file you should go for YAML parser not regex

Comment: Unfortunately, the example I included is a made up, and the real example has a weird indentation which I have tested using http://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/. It gives me `bad indentation` error. And I don't have a control over this returned string...

Answer (score 2):

Can you just:

```
let names = string.match(regex_name).map(n => n.replace('name: ',''));
```

You could also use `matchAll` and extract the groups:

```
const exp = new RegExp('name:\\s(.+)','g');
const matches = string.matchAll(exp);
const results = [];

for(const match of matches) {
  results.push(match[1]);
}
```

Or functionally:

```
Array.from(string.matchAll(exp)).map(match => match[1]);
```

For older versions of node:

```
const exp = new RegExp('name:\\s(.+)','g');
const results = [];
let match = exp.exec(string);

while(match) {
  results.push(match[1]);
  match = exp.exec(string);
}
```

```js
const string = `
   name: Mike
   age: 11

   name: Jake
   age: 20

   name: Jack
   age: 10
`;

let names = string.match(/name:\s(.+)/g).map(n => n.replace('name: ',''));

console.log(names);

const exp = new RegExp('name:\\s(.+)','g');
const matches = string.matchAll(exp);
const results = [];

for(const match of matches) {
  results.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(results);

console.log(Array.from(string.matchAll(exp)).map(match => match[1]));

//Node 8 Update
const results2 = [];
let match = exp.exec(string);

while(match) {
  results2.push(match[1]);
  match = exp.exec(string);
}

console.log(results2);
```

Comment: I am currently using your suggestion: let names = string.match(regex_name).map(n => n.replace('name: ',''));.
I cannot use matchAll() because I am using node 8 and matchAll is not supported.
Do you know how to use regex to just get the name value?

Comment: @Andy I added a pre-matchAll approach to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get the text after `name:` and [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove `undefined` values.

```js
var str = `
   name: Mike
   age: 11

   name: Jake
   age: 20

   name: Jack
   age: 10
   `;
   
const regex_name = /(.*)\b/gm;

let names = str.match(regex_name);

names = names.map(str => {
  if (str.includes("name")) {
    return str.split(':').pop().trim();
  }
}).filter(item => item);

console.log(names);
```